# Relation between two versions of Cantor's intersection theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I have noticed that there are two versions of the Cantor's intersection theorem.

(1) Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then it is complete iff for every descending sequence $(E_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of nonempty, closed, bounded subsets of $X$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\operatorname{diam}(E_n)=0$, there exists exactly one $x\in X$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n=\{x\}$.

(2) Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $(E_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a descending sequence of nonempty, compact subsets of $X$, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty{E_n}\neq\emptyset$.

I'm confused about the relation between these two propositions. They look similar, but I don't think they are essentially the same theorem.

Comment: Neither implies the other.

Comment: @geetha290krm I also agree that neither implies the other. So can I say that they are just two different theorems that happen to share the same name?

Comment: (1) is also not formulated correctly. In every metric space, closed balls around a fixed point with radii shrinking to zero have a singleton as intersection. The point is that $(X,d)$ is complete if the intersection property holds for *all* such sequences.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for your comment. I typed the question in a hurry and didn't formulate it correctly.  The only problem I have is about the NAME. Are they two different theorems that happen to share the same name?

Comment: The first one is about completeness. The second one holds for any space, even topological. And so there cannot be any possible relation between them. I really don't know why they share the name.